# SQLCommand causing duplicate Stored Proc executions

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I got an issue that I am completely stumped on.

Part of my application calls a Stored Proc using SQLConnection/SQLCommand. I'm hitting a SQL 2005 database and I am able to make the connection and execute the SP just fine. The problem is it periodically executes the SP multiple times; some times twice, some times three times.

This is basically how I execute the SP...

```
Dim conString As String = "<Typical Connection String>"
Dim cn As SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conString)
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("dbo.JobStoredProc", cn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Val", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = "Test Value"
cn.Open()
Dim queryResult As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
cn.Close()
cn.Dispose()
```

I can't figure out why sometimes it executes only once, but other times it executes multiple times. Is there something I'm missing? Is there a better way to go about executing the SP?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What method is this code inside of? What event, if any, does the method represent?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out it was because I had two of the same File Watchers looking at the same directory. This was causing the above function to fire twice at the exact same time.